# Sequelize findOrCreate method will not return newly created record

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Having issues with findOrCreate method. When record is found it returns the record and boolean, however when record isn't found it inserts new record but doesn't return it.

```
     UserAnswer.findOrCreate({where: {examId, questionId, userId}, defaults: omit(data, 'status')})
      .spread((answer, created) => {
        return res.status(200).json(answer);
      })
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you only send back the `answer` argument there... have you looked at the `created` argument? Is it there?

Comment: So when record is found, 'created' and 'answer' are returned.  However, when a record is inserted into the table, '.spread' seems to not be getting hit.